# Android: app crashed when starting after signing in release mode

Tags: android, android-keystore, release-mode

Currently I am facing an issue of app crashing when starting after signing in release mode,
but in debug mode it worked fine.

I could not figure out the problem right now,
even though i did research and keep look for solutions but i still not managed to make it works

When the app crashed it doesn't show in my app logcat but shown in "**No Filter**"

**The errors was**

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_ACTION
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:353)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.getElementsDescription(AnnotationFactory.java:75)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.<init>(AnnotationFactory.java:112)
        at libcore.reflect.AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(AnnotationFactory.java:94)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:209)
        at com.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.b.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.a.h.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.socialproperty.app.service.AppController.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callApplicationOnCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4361)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Gradle Configuration**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'keyalias'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxx'
            storeFile file('path to keystore')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
}
```

**ProGuard**

```
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Comment: can you add your proguard config file?

Comment: Hi @petey i just add the proguard rules and also the gradle configuration build

Comment: Are you using reflection? also if you don't necessarily want proguard to be enabled you can fix the crash by disabling it "minifyEnabled false"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that proguard is renaming your code and that you're using reflection.

The easiest fix would be to disable proguard (set `minifyEnabled` to false in your `build.gradle`file).

If you want to keep proguard enabled, you need to add `-keep yourclass` in your proguard rules file.
Example if I want to keep the `Activity` class:

```
-keep class android.app.Activity
```

If I want to keep all the `android.app` package:

```
-keep class android.app.**
```

More informations on proguard [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Comment: not working for me...am getting crash even after adding this..Why?