# App crashes in release mode only, how to configure proguard?

Tags: android, crash, proguard, release-mode

My app crashes in release mode only, due to proguard (confirmed, I disabled it and worked)... I see somebody had the same problem and tried some solutions like this one: [Android: app crashed when starting after signing in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747739/android-app-crashed-when-starting-after-signing-in-release-mode) .

I first tried keeping the MainActivity, then tried keeping the whole package with

```
-keep class android.app.**
```

but it still doesn't solve.
Logcat in this case is nearly useless due to obfuscation, proguard is kind of complex to understand, also because I don't find clues on which part I should tune.

Do you have any idea on how I should configure proguard?

Comment: Do you use third party libraries? If you do, check their dedicated pages to see if one of them needs some Proguard rules

Comment: If you have the mapping.txt file from your proguard build you can de-obfuscate the stacktrace using retrace in the android SDK

Comment: As @dymmeh said : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding

Comment: You didn't literally use `-keep class android.app.**`, right?

Comment: That was a third party library indeed! Thank you @Gorcyn, add the answer below if you want me to accept.

Comment: @kakaokyo No, of course :)

Comment: You can validate @Tommy's. I'm not here for points ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common problems with that is using third party libs. Check your dependency and exclude those libraries from obfuscation process.